# How to integrate $\int \frac{x^{13}\ dx}{x^5 + 1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

We get this problem from our teacher today. I only wish that it was $x^{14}$ in the numerator, so we can use substitution method:

$$\int \dfrac{x^{13}\ dx}{x^5 + 1}$$

I can't find way to integrate this. Please help me out to solve this seeming simple integral.

Comment: Hint: "seeming simple integral", no it is not. Use the general machinery for rational fractions.

Comment: Of course there is a closed form, it is just very very ugly. I wish the integrand would have been just $x$ or so...

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I get $x^8 - x^3 + \dfrac{x^3}{x^5 + 1}.$ Now what I should do?

Comment: Well you need to factorize the denominator $x^{5} + 1 = (x + 1)(x^{4} - x^{3} + x^{2} - x + 1)$ and then split further into product of quadratics and use method of partial fractions. Solution will be complicated because the quadratic factors are complicated.

Comment: You may use [this site](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNusfbg83NAhVEQ48KHcSUA_AQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.integral-calculator.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNF2mKSjmCEFrz_Zye-OjBpWuOJJIQ) to calculate this integral. An advantage of this site is that you can view all the steps also.

Comment: @samjoe: Perhaps you should ask the teacher what sense does it have to calculate it by hand. To show methods: easier examples exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\int\frac{x^{13}}{x^5+1}\,dx
=\int\left(x^8-x^3+\frac{x^{3}}{x^5+1}\right)\,dx
=\frac{x^9}{9}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\int\frac{x^{3}}{x^5+1}\,dx
$$
Note that 
$$
x^5+1=(x+1)(x^2+\phi x+1)(x^2-(\phi-1) x+1),
$$
where $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ is the "Golden Ratio". It can be shown that 
$$
\frac{x^3}{x^5+1}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{\phi x+1-\phi}{x^2-(\phi-1)x+1}+
\frac{(1-\phi)x+\phi}{x^2+\phi x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)
$$
You can take it from here...

Comment: very beautiful. how do you get the idea to factorise like that? and after that you applied the method of partial fraction right?

Comment: Not beautiful to me.  First quadratic factor of $x^5+1$ listed in the answer should be $x^2+(\phi-1)x+1$.

Comment: thanks, i just corrected it.

Comment: $(x+1)(x^2+(\phi-1)x+1)(x^2-\phi x+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

E.g. with $\frac{x^{13}}{x^5+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{5k+13}$ you can integrate easily for $|x|<1$.

---

You can simplify with $x^{13}=(x^8-x^3)(x^5+1)+x^3$.

---

The useful link of *user 170039* gives you the result for $\int\frac{x^{3}}{x^5+1}$ and shows how complicated it becomes.

---

If you like to use the proposal of *boaz*, then you need $\int\frac{ex+f}{ax^2+bx+c}=$
$$=\frac{e}{2a}\ln|ax^2+bx+c|+\frac{2af-be}{a\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\cdot\arctan\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}+C$$
for $4ac-b^2>0$ and 
$$=\frac{e}{2a}\ln|ax^2+bx+c|+\frac{2af-be}{2a\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\cdot\ln\frac{2ax+b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2ax+b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}+C$$
for $4ac-b^2<0$.

Comment: sorry sir I don't understand what you say. Please explain more about what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: He is just using the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{k\ge 0}z^k$ in the case $z=-x^5$, whose convergence radius is $1$

Comment: $\int \frac{x^{13}\ dx}{x^5 + 1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{5k+14}}{5k+14} + C$

Comment: These equalities with power series are barely justified, if at all: to use the geometric series sum we must have a common quotient *less than one* in absolute value. Here we are anti-integrating or definite integrating: we can't justify this but, perhaps, in some ring of formal series.

Comment: @Joanpemo: For $|x|<1$ it's o.k., the series is absolute convergent. The Problem is $|x|\ge 1$. The explicite solution is very complicate, I think too complicate.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, it was an accident.  Switched to an upvote.